# CSS Problem with Angular validation and PrimeNG components

Tags: angular, primeng, core-ui

When I use the "required" attribute in an PrimeNG component, I got the following problem:

[image: Screenshot 1]
The problem is, that the css style of `.ng-invalid` is on the p-calendar component and not on the input itself.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Is there a way to move the `ng-invalid` class from the component to the input INSIDE the component? It would solve my problems easy?

thanks for your help!

Comment: why don't you simply select the input using `.ng-invalid input`?

Comment: the problem is still the same: the 5px  border is on the component and not the input INSIDE the component

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The trick is to move the border from the component to the input. This isn't an exhaustive list of Primeng components, I'm adding them as I encounter them.

```
p-calendar.ng-invalid,
p-dropdown.ng-invalid,
p-selectbutton.ng-invalid {
  border-left: none;

  .ui-calendar input,
  .ui-dropdown,
  .ui-selectbutton {
    border-left: 5px solid red;
  }
}
```